# How can I access the pixels of a Reinforcement Learning environment in Google Colab?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, rendering, render, reinforcement-learning

My goal is to create an environment that provides the pixels of the frame as the observation, e.g. `env = ExampleEnv(..., from_pixels=True, pixels_only=True,)` in Google Colab. I am new to RL and I suspect that I am missing something about configuring a display, but I haven't been able to find resources explaining this for a Google Colab environment.

Creating a DMControl Environment `env = DMControlEnv("acrobot", "swingup")` without the `from_pixels` argument works but causes a warning:

```
GLFWError: (65544) b'X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing'
  warnings.warn(message, GLFWError)
```

Running it with `from_pixels`:

```
GLFWError: (65544) b'X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing'
GLFWError: (65537) b'The GLFW library is not initialized'
FatalError: an OpenGL platform library has not been loaded into this process, this most likely means that a valid OpenGL context has not been created before mjr_makeContext was called
```

Creating a VMAS environment with `from_pixels=True`:

```
NotImplementedError: vmas rendering not yet implemented
```